# Show that $\ell_1 \subset \ell_2 \subset c_0 \subset \ell^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, normal-subgroups

Let $\ell_p$ be the collection of all bounded sequences under the norm $\Vert x\Vert_p$

Let $c_0$ be the subset of $\ell^{\infty}$ consisting of all sequences that converge to $0$
(Note $c_0$ is also a normal vector space under $\lVert \cdot\rVert_{\infty}$ )

Show that we have the following propper set inclusions:

$$\ell_1 \subset \ell_2 \subset c_0 \subset \ell^{\infty}$$

---

This feels quite intuitive to me however I have no idea how to prove it, especially $\ell_2 \subset c_0$. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

If  a series $\sum a_n$ is convergent then $a_n \to 0$. Hence $(a_n) \in \ell^{2} $ implies $\sum a_n^{2} <\infty $ which implies $a_n \to 0$.

Comment: OK, Sofia should try to do the others now, without our help.

Comment: I fully agree with this comment.

Comment: ok so I do get that and I have (not very rigorously ) shown that if $a_n \in l^{1}$ then it is also in $l^{2}$ and $l^{\infty}$.   But I am still clear how to properly show it

Comment: Would it be enough to just say that if $(a_n)$ is in $l^{1}$ then it means $||x||_2 \leq ||x||_{1}  \textless  \infty $  thus $(a_n) \in l^{2}$ ?